# How do I make sure that my solution uses packages from a specific folder, that is shared on github and that it doesnt change the path on the dest

Tags: visual-studio

**Story**
So yea long title, but hear me out, I'm working on a school project where we have 4 people that share a solution over github, we have experienced issues with NuGet packages missing or the version is out of sync because we all have different versions installed.

Whenever we pull, the "project.assets.json" changes the paths for the NuGet packages config file.
I have a "nuget.config" file in the root directory of the project next to the .csproj file looking like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="repositoryPath" value="./packages-local/" />
    </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

I have created a folder on the repository where we have the packages installed we need for the solution, but everytime I set the "project.assets.json"'s paths to use the config file it swaps back to the global paths of everyone individual machine when they get pulled from github.

**Question**
How do I make sure the project's NuGet path's always point to the folder on the repository.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing the nuget packages inside the repo.  Are these "private" packages that are not available on nuget.org?

Comment: @BradleyUffner no they're public, but we kept having issues with the packages everytime we shared our progress and had to update/install the packages so I moved a copy of them to the repository and are now trying to make them files that the project uses, making sure nothing needs to be updated or installed.

Comment: It sounds like your team needs to come up with a communication mechanism around who updates packages, or when packages should be updated.  Storing them in the repo is a pretty serious anti-pattern that you won't want to follow in any serious work.  Any missing packages teammates are having *should* be getting downloaded automatically on build.  I would focus on fixing that issue rather than building a bad repo pattern.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Okay, thank you for your reply, we try to make it work without having them locally installed on the repo.